# Cannot use Abraham Williams Twitter library in Laravel 4

Tags: php, twitter, laravel-4

I am trying to create a PHP application where I use the Twitter PHP library by Abraham Williams. I am using Laravel 4 framework.

But whenever I try to create the class, the framework is giving me an error saying "Cannot redeclare class OAuthSignatureMethod_HMAC_SHA1". So far I have tried to change the name of the class and it didn't work. I have searched it in the web also. Here is my code.

```
$param = array(
    'oauth_token' => 'xxxx',
    'oauth_token_secret' => 'xxxx'
);
$twitter = new Twitter($param);
$twitter = $twitter->getConnection();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class `OAuthSignatureMethod_HMAC_SHA1` already exists somewhere else in your project, and it can't be declared twice. Perhaps you have something else which also uses OAuth?

You could namespace it, but it seems easier to just pull in any package that uses the library with Composer. Take a look at [Packagist](https://packagist.org/search/?q=twitteroauth) and read the documentation of the packages to decide which one is best for you.

After all, why reinvent the wheel when somebody else already did the hard and boring parts for you? :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. how can i use namespace to avoid error?

Answer (score 1):

Open OAuth.php

Remove this condition

```
if (!class_exists('OAuthException')) {
    class OAuthException extends Exception {
        // pass
    }
}
```